# Problems with adding Spark elements to a MX wrapper

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

So I made a simplified version of the code I'm working on ...
I have a custom Flex component that has following structure (based on the `s:HGroup`):

```
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
      width="100%" height="100%" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
        import spark.components.Button;                 
        public function addButton():void{               
            var myButton:Button = new Button(); 
            myButton.label = "New Button"; 
            buttonContent.addElement(myButton);
        }           
    ]]>
</fx:Script>        
<mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="5">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:VGroup>         
        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Group left="5" top="15" bottom="5" right="5" id="buttonContent" />
        </s:Group>          
    </s:VGroup> 
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    </s:VGroup>
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Inside this component I make use a the `mx:HDividedBox` component since there is no `Spark`alternative...

So when I call the function `addButton()`, my intend is to add a custom Spark DataGrid (in this example a simple `s:Button` made with code) to the `Spark Group` with id `buttonContent`. I noticed that this button isn't added to the `Group`with id `buttonContent`.

When I commented out the `mx:HDividedBox` the `Spark button` was added like it should... 
I suppose there is some conflict rising between the `Spark`and `mx` display formats.

Has anyone had the same problem? Or know a usable solution / work around? 
Any tips are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a runtime error or a compile time error?  Or does the button just not show up?

Comment: There are no runtime errors showing up... The button just doesn't show up ... If you paste my code, you'll see what it does ... It's quite interesting ..

Comment: I copied your code and it works as expected :-/ On a side note: I don't know your exact situation, but I would use states to include the DataGrid when needed. Let Flex take care of the dirty work for you.

Comment: It works? Strange because with me the button isn't added... How bizarre ... Thanks for the tip but the DataGrid is always added to this component :)

Comment: Then why are you adding it through ActionScript?

Comment: Because in that particular component the DataGrid can be from different types. It's a dynamic subcomponent based on the DataGrid. Adding it via ActionScript is the only way I suppose if I want to set this property from outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an "id" field to the HDividedBox.  Flex has had issues with not recognizing elements when their parents don't have an id in the past, this might be a regression issue?

(Would've added as a comment, but I don't have the access yet..)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But I tried giving the `HDividedBox` an ID , but this didn't fix the problem ... So problem still remains ... :(

Comment: have you tried calling invalidateGraphicElementDisplayList() or invalidateGraphicElementProperties() on the group or divided box?

Comment: I tried this on both (HDividedBox and the group were the grid is added) but does not have any effect ...

Answer (score 0):

Your exemple works on my computer.
Which flex SDK version are you using ?
Are you really using "100%" width and height in you real code ? (DividedBox are tricky with sizes, if you don't set resizeToContent to true then the dividedBox will not resize itself if the content changes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ... I'm using Flex 4.6.0. Every content container has the width & height set to a 100% , that's the first thing that I checked ... :) The resizeToContent property doesn't have much effect. It's a really strange issue I'm having , and still haven't sorted it out ... I'll have to spent more time on playing with some things :(